# How to add "Previous/Next" product links for Woocommerce products int he same SUB-category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to find out how to add "Previous" and "Next" buttons/links on single product pages on a Woocommerce website, but I need them to be restricted to a single subcategory. The products on our website have all have a subcategory for their respective brand , i.e. BRANDNAME, with a parent category "Brands". Now, I know how to add the links for products in the same primary category using:

```
<?php previous_post_link( 'Previous: %link', '%title', true, '', 'product_cat' ); ?>
<?php next_post_link( 'Next: %link', '%title', true, '', 'product_cat' ); ?>
```

Or this in the functions.php of the child theme:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'bbloomer_prev_next_product' );

// and if you also want them at the bottom...
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'bbloomer_prev_next_product' );

function bbloomer_prev_next_product(){

echo '<div class="prev_next_buttons">';

   // 'product_cat' will make sure to return next/prev from current category
        $previous = next_post_link('%link', '&larr; PREVIOUS', TRUE, ' ', 'product_cat');
   $next = previous_post_link('%link', 'NEXT &rarr;', TRUE, ' ', 'product_cat');

   echo $previous;
   echo $next;

echo '</div>';

}
```

However, I am completely lost as to how to modify this to limit to only previous and next product in the respective brand subcategory. Please note the that the primary category of each product is some category describing the product type, while the brand subcategory is secondary. Making the brand subcategory primary is not an option, unfortunately.

TL:DR I'm trying to add Previous/Next product links which browse only the current product's specific brand subcategory, which is a child of the "Brands" category, rather than the primary product category (say "Cosmetics") or the parent "Brands" category, itself.